# std::any_cast to get an unnamed enum?

Tags: c++, enums, c++17

I have queue of std::anys which I’m populating variadically before I know any of the types, and I’m trying to cast any unnamed enums which were passed to just be ints while populating it.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
enum {
    VALUE_1,
    VALUE_2,
};

enum {
    VALUE_3
};

template<typename ...T>
std::queue<std::any> extract_variadic_to_queue_impl(const T&... args) {
    std::vector<std::any> vec = { args ... };
    std::queue<std::any> ret;
    for (unsigned int i = 0, max = vec.size(); i < max; i++) {
        std::string type_name = vec[i].type().name();
        if (type_name.starts_with("enum <unnamed-enum>")) {
            ret.push((int)std::any_cast<???>(vec[i]));
        }
        else {
            ret.push(vec[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

template<typename ...T>
std::queue<std::any> extract_variadic_to_queue(T... args) {
     return extract_variadic_to_queue_impl(std::any(args)...);
}

#define EXTRACT(var_name, type) type var_name = std::any_cast<type>(q.front()); q.pop();

void test() {
    std::queue<std::any> q = extract_variadic_to_queue(
        0, 
        "hi", 
        VALUE_2, 
        2.0f, 
        2.0
    );
    EXTRACT(my_int, int);
    EXTRACT(my_string, const char*);
    EXTRACT(my_constant, int);
    EXTRACT(my_float, float);
    EXTRACT(my_double, double);
}
```

I know that for all unnamed enums, type_name will evaluate to “enum <unnamed-enum>-“ followed by the name of the first value (in this case, “enum <unnamed-enum>-VALUE_1”). Assuming I can’t just name the enum, what would I need to replace `???` with in order to make this work? I know it isn’t an int because `EXTRACT(my_constant, int);` throws `bad_any_cast` if I don’t check for unnamed enums in `extract_variadic_to_queue_impl`, but I assume there has to be some way to get the value, otherwise it wouldn’t let me store it at all, right?

Furthermore, does anything change if `test()` is changed to:

```
void test() {
    std::queue<std::any> q = extract_variadic_to_queue(
        0,
        "hi", 
        VALUE_2, 
        2.0f, 
        2.0, 
        VALUE_3 //now passes values from two different enums
    );
    EXTRACT(my_int, int);
    EXTRACT(my_string, const char*);
    EXTRACT(my_constant, int);
    EXTRACT(my_float, float);
    EXTRACT(my_double, double);
    EXTRACT(my_other_constant, int);

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: @TedLyngmo my b, I’m on mobile right now and assumed it wouldn’t make a difference, fixed

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to use `type().name()` to make such decisions at all, not for unnamed `enum`s or any other type. The names are completely implementation-defined. There is no guarantee what they will be (or that they will be unique).

You should check the contained type with `std::any_cast` instead or by `==`-comparing `type()` to `typeid(/*type here*/)`.

To retrieve a stored type you must have an alias for that type one way or another. Either you give the `enum` a name or you obtain the type via `decltype` from its enumerator (or a variable of its type).

Comment: well in my actual use case (which, fwiw, is a personal project that i’m working on alone so implementation-dependent factors aren’t actually a problem for me as a last resort), i don’t have access to the enums in the file which defines the extract function, but what do you mean by checking the type with any_cast? wouldn’t that just throw if i didn’t already know the type?

Comment: @HenryNissen If you don't have the type available in a translation unit, then it is impossible to retrieve a value of its type from `std::any`. In general, `std::any`'s only real use is to pass values of unknown type through some functions transparently. It is basically a type-safe version of C-style `void*` passing. For other use cases `std::variant` or polymorphism via `virtual` functions is usually the way to go.

Comment: gotcha. i had assumed (more hoped) that all unnamed enums were treated as one type since their only practical use afaik is to be treated as ints but it makes sense that they aren’t.

Comment: @HenryNissen Don't treat `enum`s as `int`s. If you want `int`s, then just declare `int` constants. The point of an enum is that it is a different type than an `int`. It essentially allows strong typing to some degree. But unscoped enums do that not very well anyway. Use `enum class` instead if you need it.

Comment: I was using enums because the automatic enumeration aspect is incredibly convenient for declaring an array with an index for each entry of the enum, sized at the last value in the enum. Though for my use case I need to have them be weakly typed or I would need to write about 120 extra boilerplate functions to handle the new types, so I might just switch over to constants, idk